# What do globes (used to construct globular sets, $\omega$-categories, etc.) actually look like?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Nlab introduces the [globular category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/globe) as a geometrical model to construct certain higher categorical structures (e. g. strict $\omega$-categories), just as quasi-categories, for example, are modelled on simplices. However, I didn't find much information on the geometric intuition behind their definition.

So, what do these globes really look like? More precisely, how is the geometric realization of globular sets obtained?

Comment: Closed balls, given their CW-complex structure with one top-dimensional cell, and two cells of every dimension down to 0. Geometric realisation is via the 'usual Kan extension' given the representation of the globe category in Top (see eg https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+realization#OfSimplicialSets where it is abstractly described, even though it emphasises simplicial sets)

Comment: So the generating morphisms $s,t$ are just the "upper" and "lower hemisphere" inclusion maps, right?

Comment: @Dominik: yes, exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paper on the fundamental [globular groupoid](http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/globularhha.pdf) of a filtered space has some pictures, and a definition of the simplicial nerve of a globular $\omega$-groupoid. Relations with other areas are in the paper M. Kapranov, "Membranes and higher groupoids" arxiv 1602.06166 .  My own philosophy is spelled out in this [Aveiro](http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/aveiro-beamer-handout.pdf) presentation.

See also [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.physics.research/8bB-vl66LBI).